# How does "call via work" in Skype4b/Lync Server 2013 work?

Tags: lync, ucma, lync-server-2013, skype-for-business

Prior to call via work (cVw) we used rcc to achieve this, since the skype for business (Skype4b) server doesn't support it anymore we want to achive the same functionality via ucma.

My thoughts on how to achieve this are roughly: create an endpoint and set the sip address as the global call via work address, then I hope in the case of a call this object would receive the relevant data (to whoom the call via work should go) so it can set all things up via tapi... As you see I don't really know how it works, I haven't found any mention of "call via work" in the ucma api so it seems like this number is really only used to create the conference call and all the relevant work happens in the server, in which case I have no chance to replace it with my own.

Is what I am trying to do possible ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a call-via-work option in the UCWA (not UCMA), called [`startPhoneAudio`](http://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/Resources-startPhoneAudio2) which is the underlying functionality of the mobile client's call-via-work function. You can actually use it with 2 arbitrary phone numbers, I've tried that and it works. Downside here is that you need an UCWA connection which is user specific, and the user which sets up the connection is the one who is showed as the "caller" on both sides of the call.

I've checked the UMCA5 SDK, what I can find related to CallViaWork is that `CallEstablishOptions` now has a property `bool UseCallViaWorkCallerIdAsPhoneUriInternal`. This triggers the call setup to set `LocalPhoneAddress` to `callViaWorkCallerId`. However, what that actually does I do not know.

Comment: I'm aware of the startPhoneAudio method in UCWA, and CallEstablishOptions would also be used to establish a call. What I want is to implement the "call via work" functionality myself, so when e.g. a call established via startPhoneAudio as a call via work call it would land in my code and I would handle it.

Comment: In that case you need to create an `MSPL` script to catch the `INVITE` and redirect to to your application: http://blog.greenl.ee/2011/09/04/rerouting-requests-ucma-application-mspl/